# Semantic UI dropdown lists displays 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I'm having difficultly getting a Semantic UI (v2.4.2) `dropdown` to work as expected.

If I click the down arrow, the `dropdown` displays a list of undefined items:

[image]

If I type the name of a tag, the `dropdown` displays the correct list of tags:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="myList" class="ui multiple search selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="tags">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Tags</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#myList").dropdown({
    minCharacters : 3,
    allowAdditons : true,
    apiSettings   : {
        url       : '//localhost:9393/tags/search?q={query}',
        onResponse: function(tags) {

          console.debug('onResponse');

          var response = {
              success: true,
              results: []
          };
          $.each(tags, function(index, item) {
            response.results.push({
              name: item.name,
              value: item.id
            });
          });
          return response;
        }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The JSON API returns a list of tags as an array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "mssql",
    "description": "Microsoft SQL Server is a relational, database-management system developed by [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/)."
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "oracle",
    "description": "Oracle's DBMS"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "plsql",
    "description": "[PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) is Oracle Corporation's procedural extension for SQL and the Oracle relational database."
  }
]
```

Oddly, the `onResponse` callback only fires when a value is typed in the search box.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you've set the minimum number of characters to initiate the search to 3 right here:

```
$("#myList").dropdown({
   minCharacters : 3,
   allowAdditons : true
```

simply add:

> showOnFocus:true

to your configuration object. It should solve the problem.